# How to change video from private to public YouTube API with Gdata for iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube-api, gdata-api

I have an iOS app that gets all the videos from a user through gdata and YouTube API. My problem comes with private videos, I need to make it so that it makes a private video public when the video is selected.

For some reason whenever I try to make the video public, I cannot edit it because the `editLink` of an entry returned by YouTube API is empty.

Here's my code someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to make the change:

```
GDataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
    [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] setIsPrivate:NO];


//GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *uploadEntry = 
//[GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
//fileHandle:nil MIMEType:@"video/mp4" slug:[[entry title]
//stringValue]];

    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

    NSString *str = [entry canEdit] ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    NSLog(@"Can edit %@", str);
    NSLog(@"Edit URL %@", [[entry editLink] URL] );

 //       NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube
                         //youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];
    ticket = [service fetchEntryByUpdatingEntry:entry
    forEntryURL:[[entry editLink] URL] delegate:self
    didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
 //     ticket = [service fetchEntryByUpdatingEntry:entry
    //delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
    NSLog(@"Ticket = %@", ticket);
   }
}

- (void)uploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
    finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry error:(NSError
    *)error {
      NSLog(@"Finished...");
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload
         failed" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upload failed: %@",
         error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        if (error != nil) {
             NSLog(@"Errors: %@", error);
            [alert show];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NO ERRORS :))");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included developer key in the request/response shown below and received the editLink in the response. You will have to relate the protocol using the oauth playground to your client-side language.

https://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/346eb7c8bdd6c3ae

Did you authenticate your requests?

Did you specify v=2?

Did you include the developer key in the query?

If your authenticated and using v=2 in the query string then you should get the edit link.

Learn the dev tools at https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/ where i made the following request specifying partial gdata fields that would contain just the **link[@rel="edit"]** tag :

```
GET /feeds/api/users/default/uploads/7dtC4kS3x08?v=2&fields=link%5B%40rel%3D%22edit%22%5D&alt=json&key=${YT-devKeyValue} HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Authorization: OAuth ya29.AHES6ZSqIlhsyFfbzZ7x-PTVR1JiTj1PjPvBbfq7RtKnaJk
```

Response includes editlink at the bottom - you should use the value of the attribute=href when you POST your update to the api:

```
{
"version":"1.0",
"encoding":"UTF-8",
"entry":{
"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
"xmlns$yt":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007",
"link":[
{
"rel":"edit",
"type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/rowntreerob/uploads/7dtC4kS3x08?v=2"
}
]
}
}
```